# React Native Expo building standalone app

Tags: react-native, expo

I use Expo for development. I don't know how to build `.apk` for Android. I checked out [Building Standalone Apps](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v18.0.0/guides/building-standalone-apps.html) documentation. It says:

> This will take a few minutes, you can check up on it by running exp
>   build:status. When it’s done, you’ll see the url of a .apk (Android)
>   or .ipa (iOS) file — this is your app.

```
exp build:android
```

I tried a few times. It's been a while. No errors, no links. Nothing on the web portal. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

expo has it's integrated system if you are using their building structure.

The building takes a while as stated. (Around 5-10mins) your build process starts with the command;

```
exp build:android
```

After a while, check the status of your build with command;

```
exp build:status
```

If your build it done, this comman will give you your .apk file url. If not, it will say your build is still in progress and try in a little bit later again.

Answer (score 0):

Expo build take some time (6-15min). You can see build progress log using link

https://expo.io/builds

Web link show all builds of your accounts. You can download old build or see log

or in short you can

```
exp build:status
```

Answer (score 0):

Your options are

1. wait, until your build is completed

- Note! If you get the following error:

```
Cannot start a new build, as there is already an in-progress build.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

then your Expo.io build is stuck. Please go to https://expo.io -> Builds and look for the latest (IOS/Android) build. If it's in "Queued" state (after 17 days as in my case), open the details and click Cancel Build.

2. Subscribe to the paid Expo.io account so you get priority in build queue.
3. Install turtle-cli and build the app locally, see https://docs.expo.io/distribution/turtle-cli/
   If it normally takes from 15-30minutes for Expo.io to build the app, turtle-cli can do it in 2-3mins.